# In TextMate 2, is it possible to change the title of the open tabs?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

In TextMate 2, when you have multiple documents open at once, and they appear in a row of tabs on the main window, is there a way to change the text (filename) shown in each tab?

By default, it shows the file's basename (the filename without any path information).  I don't want full path information displayed on each tab, but I would love to have the file's **current_directory/filename** on each tab.

(In .tm_properties, I did set `windowTitle = $TM_FILEPATH` to show the full filepath at the top of the main window, so I at least have that.)

To illustrate what I'm asking, if I have a set of files open as such:

- /Users/me/projects/code/**lib/Shapes.pm**
- /Users/me/projects/**tmp/Shapes.pm**
- /Users/me/projects/var/**data/Shapes.pm**

This is what the tabs currently look like:

`Shapes.pm | Shapes.pm | Shapes.pm`

What I would *prefer* is to see is:

`lib/Shapes.pm | tmp/Shapes.pm | data/Shapes.pm`

i.e., each file's *current* directory prepended to the filename itself.  A Perl regex would make easy work of getting that.  Does TextMate 2 give you the ability to modify the "tab title" per above?  Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge, no. I'm hoping someone will answer and tell me otherwise :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [TextMate v2.0-rc.8](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/c11b81b9da5eef388f971a70b1e96c73e06d2144/Applications/TextMate/about/Changes.md#2018-03-08-v20-rc8) (2018-03-08, installable when enabling "nightly builds") the tab title can be configured in the same manner you would do with the window title.

For example, the following configuration would give you the filename, prefixed with the name of the immediate parent directory.

```
tabTitle = "${TM_DIRECTORY/^(.*[\/])//}/$TM_DISPLAYNAME"
```

[image: tabs]

Comment: Finally! Thanks! I'll note that you must have your update preferences set to "nightly builds" in order to see this version during check for updates.

Comment: Works like a charm in TM 2.0.15. For everyone wondering where to put it: TextMate -> Preferences -> Variables tab -> click [+]. Value should be added without quotes.

Comment: @PawelPabianbbkr my example is actually referring to the `.tm_properties` file, but good to know that it works from there as well.